# Grouping duplicate values in a Powershell custom object without deleting

Tags: powershell

I have a PS custom object that is in this format:

```
|Name|Number|Email|
|----|------| -----|
|Bob| 23| bob.bob@test.com|
|Tom|124|tom.tom@test.com|
|Jeff|125|jeff.jeff@test.com|
|Jeff|127|jeff.jeff@test.com|
|Jeff|129|jeff.jeff@test.com|
|Jessica|126|jessica.jessica@test.com|
|Jessica|132|jessica.jessica@test.com|
```

I'd like to group together the fields where the numbers are the same. I.e:

```
|Name|Number|Email|
|----|------|-----|
|Bob|123|bob.bob@test.com|
|Tom|124|tom.tom@test.com|
|Jeff|125,127,129|jeff.jeff@test.com|
|Jessica|126,132|jessica.jessica@test.com|
```

I've tried a number of compare-object, sort-object, creating a new array etc. but I can't seem to get it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where / how do you get the object? Show your code please. Have you tried `Group-Object` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Group-Object` is perfectly suited for that task. With the help of calculated properties, you can create a select statement that will produce the desired output in one sweep.

```
$data = @'
Name|Number|Email|
Bob| 23| bob.bob@test.com|
Tom|124|tom.tom@test.com|
Jeff|125|jeff.jeff@test.com|
Jeff|127|jeff.jeff@test.com|
Jeff|129|jeff.jeff@test.com|
Jessica|126|jessica.jessica@test.com|
Jessica|132|jessica.jessica@test.com|
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'

# Group by name and email 
$data | Group-Object -Property Name, Email |
    Select @{'Name' = 'Name' ; 'Expression' = { $_.Group[0].Name } },
    @{'Name' = 'Number' ; 'Expression' = { $_.Group.Number } },
    @{'Name' = 'Email' ; 'Expression' = { $_.Group[0].Email } }
```

**Output**

```
Name    Number          Email
----    ------          -----
Bob     23              bob.bob@test.com
Tom     124             tom.tom@test.com
Jeff    {125, 127, 129} jeff.jeff@test.com
Jessica {126, 132}      jessica.jessica@test.com
```

**References**

[Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2)

[about calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Nice, but I think the OP wants `$_.Group.Number -join ','`